# AngularJS - Get printed value from scope inside an attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently working on an AngularJS project and I got stuck in this specific requirement.

We have a service that has all the data, `DataFactoryService`. Then, I have a controller called `DataFactoryController` that is making the magic and then plot it in the view.

```
<div ng-repeat = "list in collection">
{{list.name}}
...
</div>
```

Now, we have a requirement that pass multiple data into one element. I thought an "ng-repeat" would do, but we need to have it *inside an element attribute*.

The scenarios are:

- At one of the pages, we have multiple lists with multiple data.
- Each data has a unique code or ID that should be passed when we do an execution or button click.
- There are instances that we're passing multiple data.

Something like this (if we have 3 items in a list or lists, so we're passing the 3 item codes of the list):

```
<a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary" data-factory = "code1;code2;code3;">
    Submit
</a>
<a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" data-factory = "code1;code2;code3;">
    Cancel
</a>
```

In the example above, `code1,code2,code3` came from the list data. I tried several approach like "ng-repeat", "angular.each", array, "ng-model" but I got no success.

From all I've tried, I knew that "ng-model" is the most possible way to resolve my problem but I didn't know where to start. the code below didn't work though.

```
    <span ng-model = "dataFactorySet.code">{{list.code}}</span>
    {{dataFactorySet.code}}
```

1. The data is coming from the service, then being called in the controller, and being plot on the HTML page.

   ```
    // Controller
    $scope.list = dataFactoryService.getAllServices();
   ```
2. The data on the list are being loaded upon initialization and hoping to have the data tags initialized as well together with the list data.
3. The unique code(s) is/are part of the `$scope.list`.

   ```
    // Sample JSON structure
    [
    { // list level
       name: 'My Docs',
       debug: false,
       contents: [ // list contents level
          {
             code: 'AHDV3128',
             text: 'Directory of documents',
             ...
          },
          {
             code: 'AHDV3155',
             text: 'Directory of pictures',
             ...
          },
       ],
       ....  
    },
    { // list level
       name: 'My Features',
       debug: false,
       contents: [ // list contents level
          {
             code: 'AHGE5161',
             text: 'Directory of documents',
             ...
          },
          {
             code: 'AHGE1727',
             text: 'Directory of pictures',
             ...
          },
       ],
       ....  
    }
    ]
   ```

How can I do this?

PLUNKER -> http://plnkr.co/edit/Hb6bNi7hHbcFa9RtoaMU?p=preview

Comment: May be if you can write a jsfiddle for this problem then I can look into the exact issue. The question is not clear.

Comment: @Ashvin777 added the plunker url above: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hb6bNi7hHbcFa9RtoaMU

Comment: @georgeawg I actually thought of that, but the list contains arrays that needs to be accessed specifically. And there are multiple lists that has the data.

Comment: What it consuming the `data-factory` and `data-base` attributes? Are they AngularJS directives? Or attributes of an AngularJS directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this particular problem could be writing 2 functions which will return the baseId and code with respect to the list in loop.

I would suggest to do it like below

```
<a href = "#" data-factory = "{{getDataFactory(list)}}" data-base = "{{getDataBase(list)}}">Submit</a>
<a href = "#" data-factory = "{{getDataFactory(list)}}" data-base = "{{getDataBase(list)}}">Cancel</a>
```

//inside your controller write the methods -

```
    $scope.getDataFactory = function(list){
      var factory = list.map( (a) =>  a.code );
      factory  = factory.join(";");
      return factory;
    }

    $scope.getDataBase= function(list){
      var base= list.map( (a) =>  a.baseId);
      base= base.join(";");
      return base;
    }
```

Let me know if you see any issue in doing this. This will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! When you mentioned jquery Map, I found the solution myself by following your code! Cheers!

Comment: Great !! Thumbsup

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to pass multiple data from UI if you are using Angular.
Two-way data binding is like blessing which is provided by Angular.

check your updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTzAIiMmiVzQfSkHGgoU?p=preview) `[http://plnkr.co/edit/mTzAIiMmiVzQfSkHGgoU?p=preview]`[1](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTzAIiMmiVzQfSkHGgoU?p=preview)

What I have done here :

1. I assumed that there must be some unique **id** (I added Id in the list) in the list.
2. Pass that Id on click (ng-click) of **Submit** button.
3. You already have **list** in your controller and got the Id which item has been clicked, so you can easily fetch all the data of that Id from the list.

*Hope this will help you... cheers.*

Comment: This could be a good implementation but I need to pass what's inside the contents and not the id. Also, the requirement stated that the data tags should be there before any events or clicks.

Answer (score 0):

So basing from Ashvin777's post. I came up with this solution in the Controller.

```
$scope.getFactoryData = function(list) {
   var listData = list.contents;

   listData = listData.map(function(i,j) {
      return i.code;
   });

   return listData.join(';');
}
```